# Display name for Firebase User returns an empty String in SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

I am making a Food Delivery App with SwiftUI and Firebase, and I have been able to implement Email/Password Authentication. I have a ProfileView to display a User's Name and the vendors that they own. However when I try to access the user's displayName property it just returns an empty String. Is there any way to access or change a user's Display name from the Firebase Console.

ProfileView.swift

```swift
struct ProfileView: View {
    var user: User?
    @ObservedObject var vendorRepo = VendorRepository()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Profile")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
            
            ImageView(imageName: "examplePP", width: 100, height: 100)
            
            Text(user?.displayName ?? "No Username Provided")
                .font(.title)
            
            Divider()
            
            NavigationView {
                List(vendorRepo.userOwnedVendors) { vendor in
                    NavigationLink(destination: VendorView(vendor: vendor)) {
                        VendorRow(vendor: vendor)
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Vendors Owned by You"), displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, -25.0)
        .onAppear() {
            self.vendorRepo.readUserOwnedVendors()
        }
    }
}
```

EmailSignUpView.swift

```swift
struct EmailSignUpView: View {
    @State var displayName: String = ""
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            VStack {
                Text("Sign Up with Email")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .bold()
                
                Text("You must have an account to be able to start a vendor or modify your existing ones. If you already have an account, go to the Login Page.")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Enter your Display Name:")
                TextField("Display Name", text: $displayName)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Enter your Email:")
                TextField("Email Address", text: $email)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text("Enter your Password:")
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            }
            
            Spacer()

            Button(action: createAccount) {
                Text("Sign Up")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
    
    func createAccount() {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.password, completion: {result, error in
            var contentTitleString: String = ""
            var contentSubtitleString: String = ""
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                contentTitleString = "Sign Up Failed!"
                contentSubtitleString = error.localizedDescription
                self.password = ""
            } else {
                print("\(self.email) has been signed up!")
                contentTitleString = "Sign Up Successful!"
                contentSubtitleString = "Please restart the app for changes to take place"
                self.displayName = ""
                self.email = ""
                self.password = ""
                if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest() {
                    currentUser.displayName = self.displayName
                    currentUser.commitChanges(completion: {error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            print("DisplayName changed")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = contentTitleString
            content.subtitle = contentSubtitleString
            content.sound = .default

            // show this notification one seconds from now
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        })
    }
}
```

When I call the ProfileView View, I pass `Auth.auth().currentUser` for the `user` property.

Comment: Can you confirm that the user is logged in when ProfileView is initiated? I suspect there is no user logged in, and that the currentUser == nil, so the displayName == nil, and the "" is returned.

Comment: @TahmidAzam the button to access ProfileView is only accessible when the user is logged in. And I can also see my Owned Vendors.

Comment: Does changing the display name in ```createAccount``` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the mistake. In the EmailSignUpView's createAcount() function:

```swift
func createAccount() {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: self.email, password: self.password, completion: {result, error in
            var contentTitleString: String = ""
            var contentSubtitleString: String = ""
            
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                contentTitleString = "Sign Up Failed!"
                contentSubtitleString = error.localizedDescription
                self.password = ""
            } else {
                print("\(self.email) has been signed up!")
                contentTitleString = "Sign Up Successful!"
                contentSubtitleString = "Please restart the app for changes to take place"
                self.displayName = ""
                self.email = ""
                self.password = ""
                if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest() {
                    currentUser.displayName = self.displayName
                    currentUser.commitChanges(completion: {error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            print("DisplayName changed")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = contentTitleString
            content.subtitle = contentSubtitleString
            content.sound = .default

            // show this notification one seconds from now
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: false)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
        })
    }
```

I set the displayName to `""` before updating. Oops!

Comment: Yes I've also just found this after copying it to a local project....

Comment: Also there is no need for you to pass around a user object. You can call it anywhere in your project when implementing Firebase. For e.g. I'd change this ```Text(user?.displayName ?? "No Username Provided")``` to ```Text(Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName ?? "No Username Provided")```